# Unreachable memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, crt

Some months ago, we managed to have very few memory leaks, in fact, only 3 :

[image: Dump: 3 memory leaks]

Memory leak n°368 was a singleton which was not deleted and now it has disappeared.
But the other two were not accessible, the index for _CrtSetBreakAlloc* was not high enough to catch them.
Even if it is really sad to let them alive, we didn't really care at that time.

Then, we updated a library which is used by our software (Poet/FastObject/Versant/Actian) and after that..:

[image: Dump: a thousand memory leaks]

We managed to have ~950 memory leaks, which were not reachable with a breakpoint..

Does someone have any idea how I can track them ? We tried to go inside the loop of global variable initialization (through _initterm) but even that, we couldn't get an index low enough to break on these memory leaks..

(*) we use this piece of code to get the index and set a breakpoint :

```
typedef struct _CrtMemBlockHeader
{
// Pointer to the block allocated just before this one:
   struct _CrtMemBlockHeader *pBlockHeaderNext;
// Pointer to the block allocated just after this one:
   struct _CrtMemBlockHeader *pBlockHeaderPrev;
   char *szFileName;    // File name
   int nLine;           // Line number
   size_t nDataSize;    // Size of user block
   int nBlockUse;       // Type of block
   long lRequest;       // Allocation number
// Buffer just before (lower than) the user's memory:
   unsigned char gap[4];
} _CrtMemBlockHeader;

static long memoryBlocIndex=0;
void HKERNEL_API CheckMemoryBlocIndex() {
    char* c=new char();
    _CrtMemBlockHeader* mbh=reinterpret_cast<_CrtMemBlockHeader*>(c-32);
    memoryBlocIndex=mbh->lRequest;
    TRACE1("\nMemBlockHeader index : %ld\n\n",memoryBlocIndex);
    delete c;

    int brkValue, memoryIndex;
    std::ifstream debugfile("breakpoint.txt");

    if (debugfile) {
        std::istringstream streamLine;
        std::string sline;

        std::getline(debugfile, sline);

        streamLine.str(sline);
        streamLine >> memoryIndex >> brkValue;

        if (brkValue > 0) {
            BreakAt(brkValue, memoryIndex);
        }
    }
}

void HKERNEL_API BreakAt(long request, long notifiedMemoryBlocIndex) {
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc((request-notifiedMemoryBlocIndex)+memoryBlocIndex);
}
```

Thank you!
Sbizz

Comment: Is it your code that defines `_CrtMemBlockHeader`? That identifier is reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Why are you reinventing leak checking on Windows, which already has tools like gflags and [UMDH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak)?

Comment: Those block numbers are quite low.  A rough guess why CrtSetBreakAlloc cannot catch them would be because they get allocated too early, before your program has progressed to the CrtSetBreakAlloc assignment.  Leaks caused by object initializers are always hard to diagnose.  Consider setting a function breakpoint on HeapAlloc and making it conditional to count to 76.  Application Verifier can help too by capturing the stack trace of the allocation.

Comment: The earliest allocations (67 and 68) are apparently related to the FastObjects Runtime, and the other allocations with very close numbers are probably also related to FastObjects.  Is there a close, uninitialize, termination or similar function you're not calling?  The first 4 bytes of the other blocks could be vtable pointers (into a DLL).

Comment: The struct is the same as defined in dbgint.h.
We are already using tools provided by Microsoft : [CRT Debug Heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx#BKMK_Track_Heap_Allocation_Requests). Our project is combining MFC, WinForms, WPF which means C++, C++/CLI and C#.
Application Verifier won't work because we are mixing managed and unmanaged code. I saw that we can use _crtBreakAlloc in Watch window. I'll try.
@1201ProgramAlarm We asked to a guy who's working in FastObjects company and he told us that we are doing what it must be done.. that's why we're kind of suprised.